# react native can't dynamically change Image component source uri

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a weird issue/bug with react native (0.61.5). I have a screen where a user can change his profile picture. The picture is fetched from redux.

```
const [pp, setPp] = useState(useSelector(state => state.profile.pp))

const ppChangeHandler = async () => {
    try {
        req = await fetch(...)
        res = await req.json()
        // res.url contains the url to the new uploaded image on the server
        setPp(res.url)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I send a request to the server containing the new image (this is not included in the code, but it works), and as a response, I receive the newly generated url to the image. I want to update the profile picture on the screen to the new image once I receive the image url. But this does not work. The image dissapears and is not updated.

I'm thinking I'm facing this bug: [Image Component will not update correctly when passing in new url #9195](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9195)

I have tried the following things:

- Adding a "key" prop to  containing 'pp': `<Image key={pp} source={{ uri: pp }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />`
- Adding "cache: reload" to the source: `<Image source={{ uri: pp, cache: reload }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />`

Does anyone has a tip/workaround for this problem? The "update" of the image works, when I refresh the app, the new profile picture is showed, but I want it to show immediately, not after refreshing the app.

**Edit:** I also tried it with FastImage (https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) but I get the same result.